# How to customize arrow icon, page icon and page title in MasterDetailPage - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have created a new Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) project in Visual Studio 2015 and modified App.cs to get "hamburger menu":

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var masterPage = new ContentPage()
        {
            Content = new Label { Text = "Hello from Master!"},
            Title = "Master Page"
        };

        var detailPage = new ContentPage()
        {
            Content = new Label { Text = "Hello from Detail!" },
            Title = "Detail Page"
        };

        var mainPage = new MasterDetailPage()
        {
            Master = masterPage,
            Detail = detailPage,
            Title = "Main Page"
        };

        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = mainPage;
    }
    . . .
}
```

Everything works fine, but how can I customize these four things:

> 1) Hide / change Arrow
>
> 2) Hide / change Icon
>
> 3) Hide / change Title text
>
> 4) Hide whole toolbar

[image: MasterDetailPage]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can change arrow to hamburger icon if you use your `DetailPage` within `NavigationPage`:

   ```net
   Detail = new NavigationPage(detailPage);
   ```
2. To change icon, just change project files:

   - YourProject/Resources/drawable/icon.png
   - YourProject/Resources/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
   - YourProject/Resources/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
   - YourProject/Resources/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png

   or on your `MasterDetailPage` set `Icon` property to another resource.

   If you want to hide icon - it only applies to Android. It can be solved with custom renderer (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/):

   ```net
   public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
   {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged (e);

           var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
           actionBar.SetIcon (Resource.Color.transparent);
       }
   }
   ```

   **EDIT:**
   It can also be done in MainActivity.cs:

   ```net
   ActionBar.SetIcon (new ColorDrawable(Resources.GetColor (Android.Resource.Color.Transparent)));
   ```
3. Just use `Title` property on `Page`.
4. `SetHasNavigationBar(page, false);`

Comment: But i haven't found Resources folder in portable project, but it is available in xamarinMyProject.Droid

Comment: I used your code and got null value for `actionBar`. What I did wrong?

Comment: @JosephKatzman If your MainActivity extends from FormsAppCompatActivity then you need to use SupportActionBar instead of ActionBar.